# Creating dynamic data coming from multiple queries for SunBurst graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-structures, dataset, sunburst-diagram

I'm working on SunBurst graph using d3 for my project. I'm able to render it. The problem is for SunBurst we always have pass data in a certain format to make it work.

I have a code that takes 4 query data and merges into one. But this is very specific to 1 graph. I want it to be dynamic so that I can interchange their order.

Note: The last data should always hold **name** and **count** keys.

```
function createpayload(name, count){

  var x = {

      name: name,

      count: count,

      children: []

  }

  return x

}

function createpayloads(name, count){

  var x = {

      name: name,

      count: count

  }

  return x

}



function createPayload(projectType, subProject, status, assignedTo){

  var payload = {

      name:"My Project",

      children:[]

  }

  payload.children = projectType

  payload.children.forEach(element => {

      element.children = []

      subProject.forEach(val => {

          if(element.name == val.projecttype){

              element.children.push(createpayload(val.name))

          }

      })

      element.children.forEach((item) => {

          status.forEach(valst => {

              if(element.name == valst.projecttype && item.name == valst.subproject){

                  item.children.push(createpayload(valst.name))

              }

          })

          item.children.forEach((items) => {

              assignedTo.forEach(valss => {

                  if(element.name == valss.projecttype && item.name == valss.subproject && items.name == valss.status){

                      items.children.push(createpayloads(valss.name, valss.count))

                  }

              })

          })

      })

  })

  return payload

}
```

Here this code works but the number of inputs it takes is fixed to 4((projectType, subProject, status, assignedTo). I want this to accept any number of parameter in any order. But if I change the order how to make this dynamic enough to get the desired output?

This the the structure d3 SunBurst Accepts

```
var nodeData = {
    "name": "TOPICS", "children": [{
        "name": "Topic A",
        "children": [{"name": "Sub A1", "size": 4}, {"name": "Sub A2", "size": 4}]
    }, {
        "name": "Topic B",
        "children": [{"name": "Sub B1", "size": 3}, {"name": "Sub B2", "size": 3}, {
            "name": "Sub B3", "size": 3}]
    }, {
        "name": "Topic C",
        "children": [{"name": "Sub A1", "size": 4}, {"name": "Sub A2", "size": 4}]
    }]
};
```